# What is the main difference between Closure,Callback,Promise in JavaScript and How all are they Unique?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, closures

(I'm a beginner in JavaScript and have doubts in understanding javascript)

What my functions does?

Used Axios to get request and response from api in all three methods and log the status

This is implemented in three variants **(callback,closure,promise)**

**My Understanding:**

Legibility and readability is better in the below order:

Promise > Closures > Callback

```
//Callback

onMakeApiCallback() {
    this.getData((response) => {
        console.log("data callback success", response)
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("error is", error)
    })
}

getData(onApiSuccess, onApiFail) {
    axios.get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums")
        .then(function(response,error) {
            if(response.data[3].title === "Red") {
                onApiSuccess(response)
            } else {
                onApiFail(error)
            }
        })
}
```

The above is done using callback where i have sent a function as parameter to another function. I found this method to be complex when compared to other two.

```
//Closure

onMakeApiClosure() {
    axios.get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums")
        .then(function(response,error) {
            function innerfunction(response,error) {
                if(response) {
                    console.log("success")
                } else {
                    console.log("fail",error)
                }
            }
            return innerfunction(response,error)
        })
}
```

The above is done using Closure.Function within a Function

```
// Promise

onMakeApiPromise() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')                 
        .then(function(response,error) {
            console.log("1", response.data[3].title)
            if(response.data[3].title === "Red") {
                console.log("data is success", response)
            } else if(error) {
                console.log("error is ", error)
            } else {
                console.log("not equal")
            }
        })   
}
```

1. When to use what?
2. Is there any other difference related to performance or any other traits among these three?

Comment: There is no code in your question. Press the Edit button on [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667455/what-is-the-difference-between-closure-callback-and-promise-in-javascript) instead of posting a new one under a different account.

Comment: I suggest checking out this book: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Answer (score 0):

Links to understand

- [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)
- [Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)
- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
  to understand promises u need to first get grip of [asynchronous js](https://youtu.be/9nwPenviboM).